express-session issue with cookies
I am building an app using express.js and vue 3, and I am using session based auth, it is working great on local.
However it is not working in production. here is my code for configuring the session and the cookie:
// in app.js
app.use(
  session({
    name: "totask.sid",
    secret: config.sessionSecret,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    unset: "destroy",
    cookie: {
      sameSite: "none",
      secure: config.env === 'production' ? true : false,
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000 * 24 * 30,
    },
    store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: config.mongoose.url }),
  })
);

and here is how it is showing the cookie in browser:
cookies in browser
I have the api deployed in render and the frontend in netlify (for test)
I tried changing the configuration but I wasn't able to solve it.

so what exactly is the issue? "is not working" is not very descriptive , and the screenshot of yours doesn't show anything unusual.

the cookie has a warning sign next to it, and every time I reload the page it is gone

The problem was that the frontend and backend are on two different domains, and my browser was blocking the cross site cookies
